# Create a pairwise comparison matrices by a rule in list format

Tags: r, list, matrix

I'd like to create a pairwise comparison matrices by a rule and put the results in list format. For this I have:

## Data frame with 5 products (deltametrina,fipronil,imidaclopride,sulfluramida,tiametoxam) and 2 inviduals notes (Indv)

```
Indv<-c(1,2)    
deltametrina<-c(1,1)    
fipronil<-c(5,3)    
imidaclopride<-c(7,5)   
sulfluramida<-c(3,7)
tiametoxam<-c(9,9)
DF<-cbind(Indv,deltametrina,fipronil,imidaclopride,sulfluramida,tiametoxam)
DF
```

Now, for create a pairwise comparison matrices, my rule is the variable with highest value minus smaller numeric number of each variable. But final matrix for each individual (Indv), must to be a vector in a list object.

My output looks like:

```
[[1]]
             
               deltametrina fipronil imidaclopride sulfluramida tiametoxam
deltametrina         1         4           6             2          8
fipronil             NA        1           2             2          4
imidaclopride        NA        NA          1             4          2
sulfluramida         NA        NA         NA             1          6
tiametoxam           NA        NA         NA             NA         1
                                                                     
            
            
[[2]]

               deltametrina fipronil imidaclopride sulfluramida tiametoxam
deltametrina         1         2           4             2          8
fipronil             NA        1           4             4          6
imidaclopride        NA        NA          1             2          4
sulfluramida         NA        NA         NA             1          2
tiametoxam           NA        NA         NA             NA         1
```

This is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Why are there 1's on the diagonals? Shouldn't they be zeroes?

Comment: Where is your code to produce output? And what is desired result?

Comment: bouncyball : I need to convert zeros in 1's.

Comment: Parfait: My output I create in my hands LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you get started ...

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(DF[, -1]))
out <- lapply(df, function(x) outer(x, x, function(x, y) abs(x-y)))
out2 <- lapply(out, function(m) {
  dimnames(m) <- list(rownames(df), rownames(df))
  m
})
out2
```

Comment: Thanks Jean, help so much!!